# Unable to click element/value from the list . We can see the value only after clicking on button

Tags: list, selenium, xpath, webdriver

- 1 I enter the postcode by using sendkeys 2 I click on Find Address
  button by using click 3 Now I have to select the address from the
  list.

I tried using xpath and cssSelector but its giving me error 'no such element found'

Screenshots 
[Form Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUJF6.jpg)[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rivPf.png)

Comment: which step you are getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following xpath to click on first address in the list.

//div[@class='c-large-selector']/div/div